# Publish MVC 3.0 Site in IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, iis, publish

I program website with MVC 3.0 which uses EntityFrame work 4.0, In controller layer I Have this:

```
  public ViewResult Index()
    {
     return View(_DatabaseSMSEntities.People.ToList());
    }
```

And in View Layer I used Telerik Grid:

```
<% Html.Telerik().Grid<ProjectWebsite.Models.People>(Model)
                    .Name("People")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(o => o.PersonID).Format(
                         "<a href='../WebPage/PersonSMSPage.aspx?personID=" + "{0}" + @"' <br/>runat=""server"">" +
                         "<img src='../../Content/themes/base/images/RegisterSMS.png' <br/>alt='{0}' />"<br/>
                        );                                           

                    })
                    .RowAction(row =>
                    {
                        if (row.Index == 0)
                        { row.DetailRow.Expanded = false; }
                    })                   
                     .Render();%>
```

I published it in IIS 7.0. But it does not work.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DatabaseSMSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ModelDatabaseSMS.csdl|res://*/Models.ModelDatabaseSMS.ssdl|res://*/Models.ModelDatabaseSMS.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseSMS.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="cn1" connectionString="data source=~/ErrorsLog/Errors.db" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

First, I  published it in D:\Pardis, But I got error:

```
   CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
    An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file D:\Pardis\App_Data\DatabaseSMS.mdf failed. A database with the same name
exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file D:\Pardis\App_Data\DatabaseSMS.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Source Error: 


Line 20:         public ViewResult Index()
Line 21:         {
Line 22:             return View(_DatabaseSMSEntities.People.ToList());
Line 23:         }
Line 24:
```

Then, I published it in Inetup but I got error.
I do not have ASPNET user in user list to set security.

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work? Publishing itself or the published site?

Comment: I find I should add "User Instance=True;", but it work sometimes and does not work another time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be two problems

1. You forgot to copy your database file (If you are using sql server compact)
2. You are creating a new database through code. You should not be creating databases in your deployment environment. This can probably happen if you are using

   System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(*some strategy*)